# Installing Scala 2.9 nightly build

Tags: scala, ubuntu, scala-2.9

How to install [Scala 2.9 nightly build](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/212) on Ubuntu?

Comment: if you're on Scala 2.11 or 2.12, instead of actually installing a nightly, consider just letting sbt pull the JARs down for you as needed; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/40622878/86485

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extract it someplace and make sure its `bin` subdirectory is on the PATH, as well as `java`.

Comment: Nice short answer, but it's a little too short if Ubuntu's Scala is already installed.  You have to make sure its path appears before the pre-installed Scala.

Comment: @Rex Well, there's always your answer. :-) By the way, you can improve on it by explaining how to get scala's bash completion working too.

Comment: It's not hard to make sure your path comes first--you just have to remember to do it!  (And make sure it is loaded everywhere it's needed, which is slightly less obvious but still quite doable.)  However, Bash completion annoys me.  No thanks!  I refer the interested to http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it by hand.  I usually put my builds in

```
/usr/share/scala
```

but there are other places that make sense.  Anyway, I'd start off by

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/scala
cd /usr/share/scala
tar zxf scala-2.9.0.r24301-b20110218020036.tgz
ln -s scala-2.9.0.r24301-b20110218020036 2.9
```

Now we've got Scala in place and we have a soft link to /usr/share/scala/2.9 that we can keep pointing at new builds as we unpack them.

If you have Ubuntu's out-of-date Scala installed, you'll probably want to replace or rename those commands.  Ubuntu places Scala commands in `/usr/local/bin/`, so you need to re-point those to the right place:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/scala /usr/local/bin/oldscala
sudo ln -s /usr/share/scala/2.9/bin/scala /usr/local/bin/scala
# same thing for scalac, fsc, scaladoc
```

and then you should be set.  Ubuntu doesn't bother setting environment variables, and Scala works fine without it.

Comment: This wiki page maintains a step by step description for all OSes http://dcglab.kaist.ac.kr/wiki/index.php/Scala_Installation_Manual#Using_Scala_Installer_.28All_platform.29